# NextJS - Sentry CLI Plugin: spawn ENOMEM

Tags: webpack, next.js, sentry

I have a working nextjs repo and I want to create an automated deployment. However, running `yarn build:dev` is sometimes failing and I don't have an idea of its cause. I'm thinking this is an issue with Sentry. Any ideas will help. Thanks.

```
usertest@user-test:~/user-app$ yarn build:dev
yarn run v1.22.17
warning ../package.json: No license field
$ SENTRY_ENV=testing next build
info  - Loaded env from /home/usertest/user-app/.env.local
info  - Checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
Failed to compile.

Sentry CLI Plugin: spawn ENOMEM


> Build failed because of webpack errors
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.


usertest@user-test:~/user-app$ yarn build:dev
yarn run v1.22.17
warning ../package.json: No license field
$ SENTRY_ENV=testing next build
info  - Loaded env from /home/usertest/user-app/.env.local
info  - Checking validity of types  
info  - Creating an optimized production build  
info  - Compiled successfully
Warning: You have opted-out of Automatic Static Optimization due to `getInitialProps` in `pages/_app`. This does not opt-out pages with `getStaticProps`
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/opt-out-auto-static-optimization

info  - Collecting page data  
Page                                       Size     First Load JS
┌   /_app                                  0 B            4.88 MB
├ λ /404                                   812 B          4.88 MB
├ λ /app                                   379 B          5.18 MB
├   └ css/d0998f18980633b3.css             3.45 kB
├ λ /app/[privateKey]/[...sections]        849 B          5.18 MB
├ λ /app/[privateKey]/manage               864 B          5.18 MB
├ λ /cart                                  5.68 kB        5.13 MB
├   └ css/447237be037fa310.css             3.54 kB
├ λ /cart/success                          183 kB         5.11 MB
├   └ css/9a61a20d90862a08.css             1.53 kB
├ λ /clone/[publicKey]                     849 B          5.18 MB
├ λ /pricing/[[...step]]                   21.8 kB        5.15 MB
├   └ css/8c6576bdf86cc4f0.css             4.44 kB
└ λ /share/[publicKey]                     1.73 kB        4.96 MB
    └ css/f5297a9deccebb1d.css             2.46 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              4.88 MB
  ├ chunks/framework-5075aff02213decd.js   42.1 kB
  ├ chunks/main-1177fbd1ad012dff.js        29.6 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-4bf095f5cb645450.js  4.8 MB
  ├ chunks/webpack-03cb7ef989617708.js     3.21 kB
  └ css/457185e916b35239.css               4.34 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)

Done in 124.02s.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running out of memory for the node process. Bump it with one of:

`node app.js --max-old-space-size=8192`

`NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 node app.js`